# Constructing an isosceles trapezoid with a specific decomposition into triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons, geometric-construction

A recent question asked about finding the ratio of the bases for the following isosceles trapezoid:

[image]

That problem has been solved, obtaining a result of $|CD|/|AB|=1-1/\sqrt{2}$. What I'm curious how one would construct this figure in the first place. The solution to the original question offers some hints. Let $E$ be the central point, and let $h_1,h_2$ be the lengths of the altitudes drawn from $E$ to $AB,CD$ respectively. Then the areas of the triangles $\triangle ABE,\triangle CDE$ require

\begin{align}
\frac12 h_1|AB|=4&\implies h_1=\frac{8}{|AB|}\;,\\
\frac12 h_2 |CD|=2&\implies h_2 =\frac{4}{|CD|}=\frac{4}{1-1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{|AB|}=\frac{4}{|AB|}(2+\sqrt{2}) 
\end{align}
This determines the vertical position, but still leaves the horizontal position of $E$. Is there a straightforward way to complete this construction? (Graphical demonstrations encouraged.)

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?  If the trapezoid is fixed, the area of the left and right triangles sum to a constant, so the area of the right triangle varies continuously from 0 to (area of trapezoid - area of bottom and top triangles) as E moves along the horizontal line at height $h_1$

Comment: The ratio of perp from $E$ to $AD$ and $BC$ is also known as it is isosceles trapezium. I am thinking that may help in construction.

Comment: Knowing that this trapezium is not unique, we can construct one of them by forcing $\angle DAB = 90^\circ$ and calculate manually the height of the triangle with area $5$, with respect to base $AD$.

Comment: This is very concerning, as this question was from the 2021 AMC 12B competition. The contest was held yesterday, February 10, so I do not know how Semiclassical had access to the problem before then.

Comment: @JetChung I thought I had included it in my post, but my source for this question was DoubleKnot's question. So it goes back to that one, which you've already noticed. (If you haven't flagged those questions for mod attention, you should.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I didn't realize, thank you for pointing it out. I have flagged all of DoubleKnot's posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Since $ABCD$ is isosceles, $\angle GEI=\angle GFH$. The two triangles are similar with ratio $IG:GH=5:3$.

So after constructing $EF$ parallel to the pair of parallel sides, divide it into ratio $5:3$.